# How can i write open_basedir like this -> open_basedir = 'var/home/*/'

Tags: security, php, open-basedir

As you know. You have to write `open_basedir = '/var/home'` etc

I want to write like this: `open_basedir = '/var/home/*/'`

Which i want is php should restrict every directory which is in home directory, for every different directories.

Short question: How can i write `open_basedir` like this: `open_basedir = 'var/home/*/'`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict PHP to each user's own home directory you need a PHP setup in which:

1. PHP runs with the user credentials
2. PHP accepts a per-user configuration

A typical case is a CGI (or FastCGI) setup, rather than running PHP as Apache module. Then you can provide a custom php.ini file for each user.

BTW, I haven't tested it but perhaps `open_basedir = "~"` works as expected...

**====== EDIT ======**

Some clarifications that arise from the OP's comment:

1. In Unix shells, "~" is a synonym for "current user's home directory" so it's "/var/home/john" if you are john and it's "/var/home/michael" if you are michael. "var/home/~/" has no special meaning: it's just a directory that's called ~.
2. Many programs use this shell convention. I don't know if PHP does so.
3. CGI allows to execute arbitrary programs on the server so it is less secure than static HTML the same way that a skateboard is less secure than a space shuttle. But we are not talking about executing arbitrary programs: we are talking about executing the PHP interpreter. It'll be as as secure as PHP and your environment are.
4. If you are interested in the subject, Google for [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5?q=node/10) (a CGI implementation with enhanced performance). Many hosting providers use it.

Comment: i tested open_basedir = 'var/home/~/' didn't work. Thank you for your answer. 
Would you send a helping URL for CGI setup for providing custom php.ini for each user.
Last question : I ve heard CGI has some security problems. Is that true ?
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can. You must specify each path in the directive :

```
open_basedir = "/var/home/path1/:/var/home/path2/:/var/home/path3/"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 

But is there any automatic directory definition. ? Because there are many directories.